# In jQuery what is the way to get data and images from a json with ajax and then append them in a part of my html document?

Tags: jquery

With jquery, get data from json and then append or insert them in html document

I'm able show parsed array in console but then i'm not able to insert them in html document

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({ 
          type: 'GET', 
          url: 'https://www.rayban.com/RBClientSearchResponse? 
 catalogId=22552&langId=-1&storeId=10151&viewMode=Client&searchType=1000&searchTermScope=&sType=SimpleSearch&newpage=true&facet=&clientSide=true&pageSize=9&searchTerm=RB_WW_BrandCampaign2019_ProductsA&orderBy=', 
          data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (data) { 
          const product= JSON.parse(data.products)
          console.log(product);
          }
          });
          });
```

Comment: `$("#id").html(html);`  or `$("#id").append(html)` depending on what you need.  If your json has image data, then you'll need to convert it to a `data:` before setting `$("#id").attr("src", data)`

Comment: Before I've tried this but it doesn't work                                                     
                    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                    $('.sezione4').append($('<div>', {
                    text: products.product.productImage + products.product.name + 
                    products.product.price,
                    setTimeout: 0000

Comment: Yes, you've tried `.append()` as you stated in your question - `.append()` **doesn't work for textarea**